# How to allocate 20 MB for file received on socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets, file-transfer

I am continuously receiving "out of memory" issue.  I saw many threads and I understand that Android OS restrict major memory chunks. But how does these file sharing Applications work?

My code works fine for below 10 MB, but for 10-15 MB it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't and for 15 MB +  it never works.

Here I am trying to allocate around 11 MB and it also fails sometimes.

I tried android:largeHeap="true" in Manifest . No help.

Actually, I have to shift some videos which are already compressed. Any suggestions?

My code snippet :

```
 public class FileTxThread extends Thread {
        private  ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private  Socket clientSocket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        private BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream;
        private  int filesize = 11728640; // filesize temporary hardcoded
        private  int bytesRead;
        private  int current = 0;
        Socket socket;

        FileTxThread(Socket socket){
            this.socket= socket;
            Log.d("naval", "constructor file thread initialized");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("lvmh", "Run function  file thread");
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];    //create byte array to buffer the file
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();


                // check for SD card mounted
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
                {
                    Log.d("naval", "Mounted");
                }

                bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                Log.d("lvmh","Rceiving setting path"+imageCount);



                //System.out.println("Receiving...");


                //following lines read the input slide file byte by byte
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                current = bytesRead;

                do {
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
                    if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                        current += bytesRead;
                    }
                } while (bytesRead > -1);
                Log.d("lvmh", ">>>>>Receiving" + bytesRead);
                Log.d("lvmh",">>>>>navalllllllllll bytes read - "+current);
                bytesRead = 0; //reset


                try {
                    if(current>20)
                    {
                        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/lvmh/"+imageCount+"img.mp4");
                        videoflag = true;
                        Log.d("lvmh","Mp4 received in bytes- "+current);
                    }
                    else{
                        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/lvmh/" +imageCount+"img.jpg");
                        Log.d("lvmh","Image received in bytes- "+current);
                    }

                }catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                Log.d("LVMH","Rceiving setting path"+imageCount);


                bufferedOutputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
```

Comment: "But how does these file sharing Applications work?' -- I would expect them to read in some bytes, use them, read in some more bytes (into the same buffer used for the first bytes), use them, etc. So, in your case, use a buffer more like 16KB, not 10MB. "I have to shift some videos which are already compressed" -- what does "shift some videos" mean?

Comment: The shift means transfer over sockets. Are you saying I should use a specific buffer say 16 bytes and keep re writing it?

Comment: Well, I would use a value somewhere between 16 bytes and 11728640 bytes. I suggested 16KB, which is 16384 bytes. After all, you are already "re writing it" in your `do... while` loop, as you may not be able to read 11728640 bytes off of the socket.

Comment: Can u suggest me which section I should change? I am confused.

Comment: I suggest that you replace `11728640` with `16384`. Of course, what I *really* recommend is that you get rid of all of this and use some higher-level networking code, stuff that handles SSL and other security aspects.

Comment: I did that and                  if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                        current += bytesRead;
                        mybytearray = null;
                        mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
                    }

Comment: see that small code sample: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/IO_How_to/Stream/Copy_from_InputStream_to_OutputStream.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`socket.setReceiveBufferSize(11728640);` //11.72864 MB -- that's why sometime you fail on 10-15 MB

As, you don't need to know about impl here, you just call `socket.setReceiveBufferSize(11728640);`, it will solve your problem. impl is an instance of `LocalSocketImpl` class ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/LocalSocketImpl.java)).  But still, if you want to know more, **The implementation of setReceiveBufferSize() is as below:**.

```
public void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws IOException 
    {
        impl.setOption(SocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, Integer.valueOf(size));
    }
```

TO understand more: https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/net/LocalSocket.java.shtml

When you call `setReceiveBufferSize()`, The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled value is returned by getsockopt(2). See link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

Now, there is buffer of double size of 11728640 KB for your socket. You should not get "**out of memory**" issues.

**Please note** that **heap space** is not related to **socket**. **Socket** is related to  **Buffer**.

The default size IS 4K. You can find this information here. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_RCVBUF

`SO_RCVBUF` constant is to give hint to OS change ReceiveBuffer size accordingly.

Comment: so i have to call  setReceiveBufferSize (<Size>) byte array allocation ? what is impl.setOption?

Comment: @NavalJoshi, https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/net/LocalSocket.java.shtml. I will also update my answer very appropriately.

Comment: You were correct. It is the sockets that needs to be told the buffer size to be expected.                socket.setReceiveBufferSize(10728640);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize]; Worked for me.

Comment: @NavalJoshi, I'm also implementing it. I will enhance my answer. Glad, it solved your problem.